How can we use quartz library with jakarta namespace?
While upgrading from jersey-spring4 2.27 to jersey-spring6 3.1.3 ,we came to know that jersey 3 uses namespace jakarta while jersey 2 uses namespace javax.
But quartz scheduler library does not support for jakarta.
How can we use quartz library with jakarta namespace?
Or do I need to replace quartz with any other library?
I did changed dependency and replaced javax with javax in my project.
Code compilation is working fine but getting runtime errors(classloading exceptions mostly due to javx and jakarta?

From what I've seen, there is a 2.5.0-rc1 with jakarta based code
see maven repository and related github issue
